# Как в Laravel сделать ЧПУ с помощью .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

Имеется url вида `site.com/page/2` где 2 это ID.
Как преобразовать его в следующий вид: `site.com/page-url.html`, средствами htaccess?

Comment: Чем вас роутинг от Laravel не устроил? И зачем вы эту метку поставили, если редирект хотите делать с помощью htaccess? И что в данном случае `url` в выражении `page-url`? Slug какой-нибудь?

Comment: htaccess умеет оперировать только переменными из входяших данных и преобразовывать, то что Вы хотите сделать делаеться примером ниже, ответ от astratyandmitry

Answer (score 1):

1. Добавить в базу данных поле, к примеру `slug`.
2. В файле `routes.php` добавить

   ```
   Route::get('page/{page_slug}.html', function($slug) {
       return Page::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
   });
   ```